# What is the name and purpose of the web design technique where a single image contains multiple graphical elements?

Tags: image

I am currently trying to learn some more about web design and I used an extention on google chrome to show me all the the images on a webpage. When I did it on google.com, I found this image at https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo101.png:

[image: https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo101.png]

What is this technique called? How can I use it? Links to further material would be appreciated.

Comment: I had to post the link because I'm not allowed to post images just go to the link (its on google)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a *CSS sprite*. See e.g. [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) (or Google) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for that. I honestly did not know what it was and some of the members voted down my question (n) thanks again.